# Android issue: change parameter from general class

Tags: android

My problem is simple. But I can't solve it. Help me please guys.
I have an Activity which contains a EditText and a Button. When I type a number and press button. It could change the value from an other java file.
The actual mainFunc.java is:

```
public class mainFunc {
    private mainActivity mycontext;
    public int num = 10;
    public int mynum;
    public mainFunc(Context context){
        mycontext = (mainActivity) context;
    }

    public int getNum(){
        Random random = new Random();
        mynum = random.nextInt(num) + 10;
        return mynum;
}
```

Here is the mainActivity:

```
public Button btn;
    public EditText number;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mainFunc func = new mainFunc(mainActivity.this); 
                int newnum;
                newnum = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                newnum = func.num;
            }
        });
    }
```

Ideally, because of the change of num, mynum should be changed as well.
But, after I clicked button, the num and mynum in mainFunc.java didn't change. (I use Log.e to check them.)
Could someone tell me why?  Many thanks.

Comment: You have not called getNum() method yet!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong and I understood your question properly then, This line  `newnum = func.num;`
 should be  `newnum = func.getNum();`
You forgot to call `getNum()` method of `mainFunc` class, which will change the values of num..

**EDIT:**

Also put   `mainFunc func = new mainFunc(mainActivity.this);`  this line in onCreate() out of button's click method..

something like,

```
public Button btn;
public EditText number;
mainFunc func;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        func  = new mainFunc(mainActivity.this); 

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                int newnum;
                newnum = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
                newnum = func.getNum();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: func.getNum() is return mynum -- the random number plus 10. not the num. I want to change the value of num, so that mynum will change as well.

Answer (score 0):

You create an mainFunc instance each time the onClickListener being triggered.

The num will always be 10. And you create a Random instance each time in method getNum, that's could be the reason why the values remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

you need static values of num and munum which are needed as data:

Answer (score 0):

As per you comment , if you want to change the value of num,

```
func.num=newnum;
int test=func.getnum();
```

make num as static;

If you print the values i think you got what you need mynum also changed i think.